# Spring data neo4j 4: RelationshipOperationsRepository

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In older versions SDN we had following interface for repositories

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.RelationshipOperationsRepository;

public interface UserRelationRepository extends GraphRepository<UserEntity>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<UserEntity> {

 MakeFriend rel = userRepository.getRelationshipBetween(startUser, endUser, MakeFriend.class, RelTypes.FRIEND.name());
        if (rel != null) {
            startUser.getFirstname() + " + " + endUser.getFirstname());
        }

        userRepository.createRelationshipBetween(startUser, endUser, MakeFriend.class, RelTypes.FRIEND.name());
        userRepository.createRelationshipBetween(endUser, startUser, MakeFriend.class, RelTypes.FRIEND.name());
```

But current version does not support it. Which is the best way implement functionality like createRelationshipBetween or getRelationshipBetween in SDN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDN 4 does not support managing low-level graph operations using APIs.

Instead the graph operations to be performed are inferred from your domain model classes and what you do with them.

For example, create a `User` class as follows:

```
class User {

   List<User> friends = new ArrayList();
}
```

If you now adding or remove Users in the `friends` list and save the User in the normal way via the standard Repository methods, this will achieve what you need automatically - the appropriate relationships will be added/removed. You don't have to tell SDN what to do because the point of an ORM/OGM is to hide you from the underlying data model and its implementation details and allow you to manipulate the domain model itself.

If you really need to perform these low-level operations directly on the graph, you use Cypher with a query method.

You can find out more about SDN 4.1 [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/)